# How do I create a class from XML elements?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an anonymous type used in a Linq query and want to make this a class instead of anonymous type.

The fields are: Age and an XML node that has a couple of elements. How do I declare the class so that I can access the XML elements?

Here's the partially declared class:

```
class Student {
    int Age;
    // ??? What to use here for the XML node? XElement? 
}
```

Comment: Define types like in an anonymous class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you looking for..

To explain i have created an example..

I have created student class that look like this

```
   public class Student
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string XmlData { get; set; }

    public Student()
    {

    }


}
```

I created Course class. this class will be initiate by the values from the xml

```
   public class Course
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }

    public Course()
    {

    }
}
```

now look the code...

```
Student student = new Student();
        student.Age = 120;
        student.XmlData = "<root><courses><course id='0'><name>Name a</name><grade>88</grade></course><course id='1'><name>Name a</name><grade>88</grade></course><course id='2'><name>Name a</name><grade>88</grade></course><course id='3'><name>Name a</name><grade>88</grade></course></courses></root>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(student.XmlData);

        List<Course> coursesData = (from c in doc.Element("root").Element("courses").Elements("course")
                                   select new Course()
                                              {
                                                  Name = c.Element("name").Value,
                                                  Grade = Convert.ToInt16(c.Element("grade").Value)
                                              }).ToList();
```

- create new instance of a student.
- insert the value 120 for age
- insert xml value to student.Xmldata parameter
- create linq query and initiate list of courses

I hope it help you

Comment: Thanks so much. This is the direction I need.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand is you have some XML something like this:

```
<student>
    <age></age>
    <innerNode>
        <node1></node1>
        <node2></node2>
    <innerNode>
</student>
```

and you want to represent this in a c# class. I would suggest having 2 classes. 1 for the Student and then another for the innerNode.

In your Student class you will have the properties:

```
int Age { get; };
innerNodeClass Inner { get; }
```

Then you will be able to do Student.Inner.Node1.